# Get date as a string from datetime object in doctrine 2

Tags: php, datetime, doctrine, doctrine-orm

In one of my entities, I have a protected property called `insert_date` which is a datetime.

When I extract the data afterwards, I don't get the date as a string, I get an object. My var dump:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'> <b>object</b>(<i>DateTime</i>)[<i>1560</i>] <i>public</i> 'date' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2011-08-26 12:40:29'</font> <i>(length=19)</i> <i>public</i> 'timezone_type' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>3</font> <i>public</i> 'timezone' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Europe/London'</font> <i>(length=13)</i> </pre><pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'> <b>object</b>(<i>DateTime</i>)[<i>1571</i>] <i>public</i> 'date' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'2011-08-26 12:40:29'</font> <i>(length=19)</i> <i>public</i> 'timezone_type' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>3</font> <i>public</i> 'timezone' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Europe/London'</font> <i>(length=13)</i>
```

I tried:

```
foreach($dateObj as $date) {

}
```

But it doesn't extract ...  How can I get the date property from this object? Even `$insert_date->date` doesn't work.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

use

```
if($dateObj)
{
    $dateObj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object ??

Comment: Some of your records might have `NULL` in the db. Check `$dateObj` is not empty before formatting it: `if (!empty($dateObj)) $dateObj->format(...)`.

Answer (score 15):

To make sure that your $dateObj is an actual datetime obj use:

```
if($dateObj instanceof \DateTime){
    $dateObj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

using "instanceof" checks that the object will have the required format function thus wont throw errors if it isnt.